# Android content view not yet created

Tags: android, eclipse

I use three fragments in the MainActivity.

And it comes out of the fata exception: main. Says that,
the RequestFragment.class line 54 is the cause of the exception:

```
adapter = new RequestAdapter(getListView().getContext(), mRequests);
```

The **RequestAdapter** is a class implementated separatedly.

Thanks! 
**Code:**

```
@Override

public void onResume() {

        super.onResume();

        getActivity().setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
        currentUserName = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getUsername();
        getActivity().setProgressBarIndeterminate(true);
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>(ParseConstants.CLASS_ACTIVITYREQUEST);
        query.whereEqualTo(ParseConstants.KEY_RECIPIENTNAME, currentUserName);
        //Reorder the result according to the time users shake the phone
        query.addDescendingOrder(ParseConstants.KEY_CREATEDAT);
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {

            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseObject> requests, ParseException e) {
                getActivity().setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
                if(e == null){
                    mRequests = requests;
                    adapter = new RequestAdapter(getListView().getContext(), mRequests);
                    setListAdapter(adapter);
                }
                else{
                    Log.d(TAG, "no request");
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: instead of using getListView().getContext() u can use , getActivity()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change here

```
adapter = new RequestAdapter(getListView().getContext(), mRequests);
```

to

```
adapter = new RequestAdapter(getActivity(), mRequests);
```